What does process philosophy contribute to cognitive science?
What does process philosophy contribute to cognitive science?
Is it newer constructs, hypotheses, or something else?

I'd say primarily (the form of) an ontology, so surely the "constructs", but that means the very terms of the problem, in other words its "matter", where the "matter" here is "processes".  For example, <>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_philosophy#Whitehead's_actual_entities  --  I would convert that into an answer, if that's enough (simple question, simple answer): or, would you have any specific doubts?
